# D3 Force layout fix positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm using D3's forced layout graph to plot the data.

When I call the `update` function using `setInterval` with new data, the force layout graph nodes start from a random position. How can I fix this?

I read other answers such as using `d.x d.y` or `alpha(0)` , in case of `alpha(0)` it did not work but `d.x d.y` using was successful until the data is changed and then the new node is not in same position as it is supposed to be.

My Current working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mootqvs1/5/

Answer (score 0):

In D3.js version 3 you have a property fixed for the node to stay at the current position. In version 4 this property is replaced with d.fx and d.fy, if they are set the node will stay at that position.